# How to access current child ng-repeat object in parent ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.5.8 and slick slider 1.6.0. In my project, I have one parent ng-repeat and a child ng-repeat. My slick slider contains one ng-repeat which receives images from API data. My current parent ng-repeat object is referred as 'key' while my current child ng-repeat object is referred as 'thumbkey' (in key.allimages). I need to take current thumbkey object outside slick slider for some manipulations.

(If I could get 'thumbkey' object on 'init' or 'afterchange' event of slider, it would be better as I want to change some values inside the object).

I am using Angular directive for slick "angular-slick-carousel".

```
    <div class="sub-container" ng-repeat="key in getStreamResponse track by $index" pik-id="{{key.pik_id}}">
<!--This code in inside slick slider (Start)-->
                <div ng-repeat="thumbkey in key.allimages track by thumbkey.pik_name">
                    <div class="story-header">
                        <div class="story-header-pic">
                            <img class="story-profile-pic" ui-sref="user-profile.story({userid:encodeUserId(key.piklist_user_id)})" src="Resources/spyguy.png" actual-image="{{path}}/profile/{{key.piklist_profile_pic}}" width="40" height="40">
                        </div>
                        <div class="story-header-content">
                            <div class="story-name default-pikmobile-font" ng-show="key.piklist_name != ''" ng-bind="key.piklist_name"></div>
                            <div class="null-originator-story-name default-pikmobile-font" ng-show="key.piklist_name == ''" ng-bind="thumbkey.user_name"></div>
                            <div class="story-header-user" ng-if="key.piklist_name != ''">
                                <span class="normal-text">by</span>
                                <span class="user-name" disable-sref-if="thumbkey.user_id == selfInfo.id" ui-sref="user-profile.story({userid:encodeUserId(thumbkey.user_id)})" ng-bind="thumbkey.user_name"></span>
                                <span class="original-user-name" disable-sref-if="thumbkey.originator_id == selfInfo.id" ng-if="(thumbkey.user_name != thumbkey.originator_username) && thumbkey.originator_username != '' "><span class="original-photo-text" ui-sref="story-page({pikid:encodeStoryId(thumbkey.pikd_pik_id)})">Original photo</span> <span class="normal-text">by </span><span class="originator" ui-sref="user-profile.story({userid:encodeUserId(thumbkey.originator_id)})" ng-bind="thumbkey.originator_username"></span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="story-upload-time" ng-if="thumbkey.origin_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'" ng-bind="getUploadTime(thumbkey.origin_date)"></div>
                        <div class="story-upload-time" ng-if="thumbkey.origin_date == '0000-00-00 00:00:00'" ng-bind="getUploadTime(thumbkey.date_time)"></div>
                    </div>
</div>
<!--This code in inside slick slider (End)-->
</div>
```

Comment: please share some code

Comment: You may be the newbie so let me tell .... you don't ask for complete solution and code here ... you have to paste what you have done so far and we can fix there if any logical functional err in the code  .... so try it firt yourself

Comment: Hi @fabiosilvalima, I have shared required part of code.

Comment: @GeniusGo, as `key.allimages` has more `thumbkey` object, which object you refer as current object to access the same from the parent? Can you explain the purpose and any condition to get one of the object.

Comment: when you say you want to get the "current" `thumbkey`, how are you determining which one is "current" when you are displaying them all on the page?

Comment: @Aruna and @Claies, I can get current slide for each slider using slider's function `$(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide))`, but object I get from it is slider's object and not exact `thumbkey` object. So I can't modify the property of object as I need to do it after successful API call.